# Is there any maven command can run on Jenkins shell to analyze typescript code in SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, typescript, sonarqube, tslint

I want to do static code analyze for typescript Jenkins job using SonarQube. I can do it by installing tsLint lib to my project and compile gulp file in Jenkins, but I think it is not a developer friendly method. Is there any maven command can run on Jenkins shell to analyze typescript code in SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sonarqube plug-in https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin... This plugin works with tslint but it is no official sonarqube plugin... In my case it works perfectly

Comment: Can it run on a Jenkins job.